# Is it possible to use both diamondback and electric in same OS?

Tags: ros, installation, ros-diamondback, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am in a situation such that to use both diamondback and electric. Is it possible to use both the versions of ros in a same operating system?

If possible, how?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41991/is-it-possible-to-use-both-diamondback-and-electric-in-same-os?/) by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2012-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I answered this previously [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11285/upgrading-to-electric-then-what/#16747). Hopefully that will also make it clear how to treat the contents of your `.bashrc` file. Note that if you have your own source code then you will need to rebuild it after switching which version of ROS you are using.

As @joq says you will find it very difficult (at best) to use two versions of ROS at the same time. You may find more success in using the newer version of ROS as a system install, then any packages (or stacks) that you want to use from older versions of ROS you can install and build from source in one of your user directories. That approach has its own downsides (find fixes to make package work with newer version of ROS) but will be much easier than using two versions of ROS.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, this is possible. If you have both ROS versions installed, you can use e.g. use Diamondback in one Terminal by sourcing the setup.bash of Diamondback:

```
source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash
```

and use Electric by sourcing the setup.bash of Electric in another terminal:

```
source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-22**:
I have some questions regarding that

1. In 'bashrc', Should I write source for diamondback or electric or both
2. If both what will be the result for 'echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH'
3. What will be the result about trying to find a common package for both version. EX. rospack find openni_kinect.

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-22**:
What do you mean by "write source for diamondback or electric"? Why do you actually want to use both? If possible you should better use only Fuerte...

**Comment by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) on 2012-08-22**:
In 'bashrc' file, Should I write 'source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash' and 'source /opt/ros/diamondback/setup.bash'?

I am trying to use package RGBDSLAM and 3d_navigation. So, I need both versions

**Comment by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) on 2012-08-22**:
Your bashrc will be loaded every time you start a new terminal. So you source the ROS version that should be loaded by default in your .bashrc ... if you want to use the other ROS version, you will have to source it manually in another terminal

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-22**:
*Do* *not* try to run them both at once.